# Scrollable box containing list of Checkboxes in HTML

Tags: iframe, html, checkbox, scrollable

Attached you'll see a picture of a mock up I did for the required UI. As you can see I need some type of scrollable box that contains checkboxes.

[image]

I've thought of a scrollable div, although I can't find a way to set a border around a div? Second I thought of an IFrame.. But also not too sure if this is my best option.

Does anybody perhaps have an easier/better way of doing this?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

CSS:

```
.container { border:2px solid #ccc; width:300px; height: 100px; overflow-y: scroll; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="checkbox" /> This is checkbox <br />
    <input type="checkbox" /> This is checkbox <br />
    <input type="checkbox" /> This is checkbox <br />
    <input type="checkbox" /> This is checkbox <br />
    <input type="checkbox" /> This is checkbox <br />
    <input type="checkbox" /> This is checkbox <br />
    <input type="checkbox" /> This is checkbox <br />
    <input type="checkbox" /> This is checkbox <br />
    <input type="checkbox" /> This is checkbox <br />
    <input type="checkbox" /> This is checkbox <br />
</div>
```

How it looks:

[image: design]

Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 9):

```
<style type="text/css">
   select, ul { height: 100px; overflow: auto; width: 100px; border: 1px solid #000; }
   ul { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow-x: hidden; }
   li { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
   label { display: block; color: WindowText; background-color: Window; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; }
   label:hover { background-color: Highlight; color: HighlightText; }
  </style>
<ul>
   <li><label for="chk1"><input type="checkbox" name="chk1" id="chk1">First</label></li>
   <li><label for="chk2"><input type="checkbox" name="chk2" id="chk2">Second</label></li>
   <li><label for="chk3"><input type="checkbox" name="chk3" id="chk3">Third</label></li>
   <li><label for="chk4"><input type="checkbox" name="chk4" id="chk4">Fourth</label></li>
   <li><label for="chk5"><input type="checkbox" name="chk5" id="chk5">Fifth</label></li>
   <li><label for="chk6"><input type="checkbox" name="chk6" id="chk6">Sixth</label></li>
   <li><label for="chk7"><input type="checkbox" name="chk7" id="chk7">Seventh</label></li>
  </ul>
```

http://krijnhoetmer.nl/stuff/html/select-multiple-checkbox-list/

Answer (score 2):

A variant:

```js
function obtenerSeleccionados() {
  var seleccionados = [];
  $('.contenedor input:checked').each(function() {
    seleccionados.push($(this).attr('id'));
  });
  alert(seleccionados);
}
```

```css
.contenedor {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: fixed;
  background: white;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

  Hito:

  <input id='btnAbrirFiltro' type="button" value="Filtro múltiple" onclick="$('.contenedor').toggle();$('#btnFiltrar').toggle();$('#btnAbrirFiltro').toggle();$('#btnCerrarFiltro').toggle();">

  <input id='btnCerrarFiltro' type="button" value="Cerrar" style="display: none;" onclick="$('.contenedor').toggle();$('#btnFiltrar').toggle();$('#btnAbrirFiltro').toggle();$('#btnCerrarFiltro').toggle();">

  <input id='btnFiltrar' type="button" value="Filtrar" style="display: none;" onclick="obtenerSeleccionados()">

  <div class="contenedor" style="display: none;">
    <input id="cfh_1" type="checkbox" /> Hito 1
    <br />
    <input id="cfh_2" type="checkbox" /> Hito 2
    <br />
    <input id="cfh_3" type="checkbox" /> Hito 3
    <br />
    <input id="cfh_4" type="checkbox" /> Hito 4
    <br />
    <input id="cfh_5" type="checkbox" /> Hito 5
    <br />
    <input id="cfh_7" type="checkbox" /> Hito 6
    <br />
    <input id="cfh_8" type="checkbox" /> Hito 7
    <br />
    <input id="cfh_4567" type="checkbox" /> Hito 8
    <br />
    <input id="cfh_345" type="checkbox" /> Hito Implementación final del evento
    <br />
    <input id="cfh_45671" type="checkbox" /> Hito a8
    <br />
    <input id="cfh_45672" type="checkbox" /> Hito s8
    <br />
    <input id="cfh_45673" type="checkbox" /> Hito d8
    <br />
    <input id="cfh_45674" type="checkbox" /> Hito f8
    <br />
    <input id="cfh_45675" type="checkbox" /> Hito g8
    <br />
  </div>

</div>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, libero nullam dolor, auctor consequat. Risus donec nunc nulla maecenas, at mattis, arcu tempor. Faucibus velit vitae arcu mauris, sem blandit elementum. Conubia pede interdum urna suspendisse eget. Vestibulum malesuada amet
ac vel ligula, leo aenean, ac ultrices nec class, consectetuer adipiscing massa in sint morbi justo, sit maecenas a sit. Enim molestie, porta enim, dolor suscipit sagittis, donec ornare sed aenean aliquet parturient blandit. Quisque nisl tempus arcu lobortis
massa quis, pede praesent nulla et eget sed, facilisi nunc elit erat. Volutpat mauris pellentesque magna aliquam dolor facilisi. Nec orci, nunc imperdiet feugiat. Erat est vestibulum nec et, eu eros tempus morbi netus, congue pellentesque vivamus, tellus
eleifend maecenas mus sodales blandit et, sed vulputate rhoncus lobortis amet id inceptos. Magna vestibulum elit vel aenean, aliquam praesent vestibulum sed fringilla amet volutpat, cras mauris suscipit pretium.
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function obtenerSeleccionados() {
  var seleccionados = [];
  $('.contenedor input:checked').each(function() {
    seleccionados.push($(this).attr('id'));
  });
  alert(seleccionados);
}
```

```css
.contenedor {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: fixed;
  background: white;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

  Hito:

  <input id='btnAbrirFiltro' type="button" value="Filtro múltiple" onclick="$('.contenedor').toggle();$('#btnFiltrar').toggle();$('#btnAbrirFiltro').toggle();$('#btnCerrarFiltro').toggle();">

  <input id='btnCerrarFiltro' type="button" value="Cerrar" style="display: none;" onclick="$('.contenedor').toggle();$('#btnFiltrar').toggle();$('#btnAbrirFiltro').toggle();$('#btnCerrarFiltro').toggle();">

  <input id='btnFiltrar' type="button" value="Filtrar" style="display: none;" onclick="obtenerSeleccionados()">

  <div class="contenedor" style="display: none;">
    <input id="cfh_1" type="checkbox" /> Hito 1
    <br />
    <input id="cfh_2" type="checkbox" /> Hito 2
    <br />
    <input id="cfh_3" type="checkbox" /> Hito 3
    <br />
    <input id="cfh_4" type="checkbox" /> Hito 4
    <br />
    <input id="cfh_5" type="checkbox" /> Hito 5
    <br />
    <input id="cfh_7" type="checkbox" /> Hito 6
    <br />
    <input id="cfh_8" type="checkbox" /> Hito 7
    <br />
    <input id="cfh_4567" type="checkbox" /> Hito 8
    <br />
    <input id="cfh_345" type="checkbox" /> Hito Implementación final del evento
    <br />
    <input id="cfh_45671" type="checkbox" /> Hito a8
    <br />
    <input id="cfh_45672" type="checkbox" /> Hito s8
    <br />
    <input id="cfh_45673" type="checkbox" /> Hito d8
    <br />
    <input id="cfh_45674" type="checkbox" /> Hito f8
    <br />
    <input id="cfh_45675" type="checkbox" /> Hito g8
    <br />
  </div>

</div>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, libero nullam dolor, auctor consequat. Risus donec nunc nulla maecenas, at mattis, arcu tempor. Faucibus velit vitae arcu mauris, sem blandit elementum. Conubia pede interdum urna suspendisse eget. Vestibulum malesuada amet
ac vel ligula, leo aenean, ac ultrices nec class, consectetuer adipiscing massa in sint morbi justo, sit maecenas a sit. Enim molestie, porta enim, dolor suscipit sagittis, donec ornare sed aenean aliquet parturient blandit. Quisque nisl tempus arcu lobortis
massa quis, pede praesent nulla et eget sed, facilisi nunc elit erat. Volutpat mauris pellentesque magna aliquam dolor facilisi. Nec orci, nunc imperdiet feugiat. Erat est vestibulum nec et, eu eros tempus morbi netus, congue pellentesque vivamus, tellus
eleifend maecenas mus sodales blandit et, sed vulputate rhoncus lobortis amet id inceptos. Magna vestibulum elit vel aenean, aliquam praesent vestibulum sed fringilla amet volutpat, cras mauris suscipit pretium.
```

```js
function obtenerSeleccionados() {
  var seleccionados = [];
  $('.contenedor input:checked').each(function() {
    seleccionados.push($(this).attr('id'));
  });
  alert(seleccionados);
}
```

```css
.contenedor {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: fixed;
  background: white;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

  Hito:

  <input id='btnAbrirFiltro' type="button" value="Filtro múltiple" onclick="$('.contenedor').toggle();$('#btnFiltrar').toggle();$('#btnAbrirFiltro').toggle();$('#btnCerrarFiltro').toggle();">

  <input id='btnCerrarFiltro' type="button" value="Cerrar" style="display: none;" onclick="$('.contenedor').toggle();$('#btnFiltrar').toggle();$('#btnAbrirFiltro').toggle();$('#btnCerrarFiltro').toggle();">

  <input id='btnFiltrar' type="button" value="Filtrar" style="display: none;" onclick="obtenerSeleccionados()">

  <div class="contenedor" style="display: none;">
    <input id="cfh_1" type="checkbox" /> Hito 1
    <br />
    <input id="cfh_2" type="checkbox" /> Hito 2
    <br />
    <input id="cfh_3" type="checkbox" /> Hito 3
    <br />
    <input id="cfh_4" type="checkbox" /> Hito 4
    <br />
    <input id="cfh_5" type="checkbox" /> Hito 5
    <br />
    <input id="cfh_7" type="checkbox" /> Hito 6
    <br />
    <input id="cfh_8" type="checkbox" /> Hito 7
    <br />
    <input id="cfh_4567" type="checkbox" /> Hito 8
    <br />
    <input id="cfh_345" type="checkbox" /> Hito Implementación final del evento
    <br />
    <input id="cfh_45671" type="checkbox" /> Hito a8
    <br />
    <input id="cfh_45672" type="checkbox" /> Hito s8
    <br />
    <input id="cfh_45673" type="checkbox" /> Hito d8
    <br />
    <input id="cfh_45674" type="checkbox" /> Hito f8
    <br />
    <input id="cfh_45675" type="checkbox" /> Hito g8
    <br />
  </div>

</div>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, libero nullam dolor, auctor consequat. Risus donec nunc nulla maecenas, at mattis, arcu tempor. Faucibus velit vitae arcu mauris, sem blandit elementum. Conubia pede interdum urna suspendisse eget. Vestibulum malesuada amet
ac vel ligula, leo aenean, ac ultrices nec class, consectetuer adipiscing massa in sint morbi justo, sit maecenas a sit. Enim molestie, porta enim, dolor suscipit sagittis, donec ornare sed aenean aliquet parturient blandit. Quisque nisl tempus arcu lobortis
massa quis, pede praesent nulla et eget sed, facilisi nunc elit erat. Volutpat mauris pellentesque magna aliquam dolor facilisi. Nec orci, nunc imperdiet feugiat. Erat est vestibulum nec et, eu eros tempus morbi netus, congue pellentesque vivamus, tellus
eleifend maecenas mus sodales blandit et, sed vulputate rhoncus lobortis amet id inceptos. Magna vestibulum elit vel aenean, aliquam praesent vestibulum sed fringilla amet volutpat, cras mauris suscipit pretium.
```

Answer (score -2):

if u have aray then use this function in PHP

```
        function addOCheckBoxValuesByArray($arr) {      
                foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
                echo"<input type= 'checkbox' name='formBylist[]' value='$value' />$value<br />";
                }

        }



    below code access data after user press submit button

    if(isset($_POST['formBylist']))
        {   
            $selectedDataBylist = $_POST['formBylist'];
            if(!isset($selectedDataBylist))
            {  // is data not selected
                echo "You didn't select data from below checkbox Table";
            }
            else
            { // data is user selected
                $Cnt = count($selectedDataBylist);

                for($i=0; $i < $Cnt; $i++)
                {           
                $result =$selectedDataBylist[$i]);

                    }
    }
    enter code here

}



to put all check boxes in scroll bar - use CSS 

<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>
.container { border:2px solid #ccc; width:400px; height: 500px; overflow-y: scroll; } 
</style>
</head>



///
<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">         
                <div class="container">             
                                   addOCheckBoxValuesByArray($chekboxarray);?>
                </div>




    enter code here
```