# CheckBox List from dynamic values

Tags: html, vbscript, asp-classic

I am working on a classic ASP page in VB both of which I am not hugely familiar with. I am trying change this

[image]

to this

[image]

Which should be pretty straight forward except it looks like the list is dynamic and its tripping me up.

```
 <% sendtomenu = sendtomenu + "<option value = " & trim(Recordset2.Fields.Item("linkfile").Value) & ">" & trim(Recordset2.Fields.Item("description").Value) & "</option>" %>


    <td width="231" height="25"> <select name="sendto" size="2" multiple class="blacktype" id="sendto">
            <% Response.write sendtomenu %>
```

Comment: What specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: I am not sure how to turn what i have there into something more like this   <div class="container">
    <input type="checkbox" /> This is checkbox <br />
    <input type="checkbox" /> This is checkbox <br />
    <input type="checkbox" /> This is checkbox <br />
    <input type="checkbox" /> This is checkbox <br />
    <input type="checkbox" /> This is checkbox <br />
    <input type="checkbox" /> This is checkbox <br />
    <input type="checkbox" /> This is checkbox <br />
  
</div>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280389/scrollable-box-containing-list-of-checkboxes-in-html

Comment: Thanks for the down vote some info would be most helpful

Comment: Your tags are self-contradictory: is this asp.net (and vb.net), or is it asp-classic (and vbscript)?

Comment: The page i am working on is asp-classic and vb script. Neither of which i have any familiarity with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get markup similar to this:

```
<div id="CheckedListBox1" style="border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;height:100px;width:300px;overflow-y:scroll;padding:2px;">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cb1" /><label for="cb1">This is checkbox1</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cb2" /><label for="cb2">This is checkbox2</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cb3" /><label for="cb3">This is checkbox3</label><br>
    ... 
</div>
```

You most likely have a dynamic list (or probably recordset). You can loop thru it.
You can adapt this solution as per your needs. (Replace i with whatever values.)

```
<div id="CheckedListBox1" style="border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;height:100px;width:300px;overflow-y:scroll;padding:2px;">
    <% For i = 1 To 10 %>
        <input type="checkbox" id=cb<% =i %> value=<% =i %> />
        <label for=cb<% =i %>>This is checkbox<% =i  %></label><br>
    <% Next %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the checkboxes list, you should use the `CheckedListBox` control.

**aspx markup:**

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" ></asp:CheckBoxList>
```

**In the code-behind:**

```
Private Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    '' this is the most simplest example of adding items. you may use databinding etc.
    CheckBoxList1.Items.Add("This is checkbox 1")
    CheckBoxList1.Items.Add("This is checkbox 2")
    CheckBoxList1.Items.Add("This is checkbox 3")
    CheckBoxList1.Items.Add("This is checkbox 4")
    CheckBoxList1.Items.Add("This is checkbox 5")
    CheckBoxList1.Items.Add("This is checkbox 6")
    CheckBoxList1.Items.Add("This is checkbox 7")
    CheckBoxList1.Items.Add("This is checkbox 8")
    CheckBoxList1.Items.Add("This is checkbox 9")
End Sub
```

To get the scrollbars, you should enclose the `CheckedListBox` in a `Panel` with `ScrollBars` property set to `Vertical`

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" ScrollBars="Vertical" Width="300px" Height="100px">
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" ></asp:CheckBoxList>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Thanks, since this is classic asp i wasnt sure if i could use asp controls.

Comment: Ok.. you put both vb.net and classic-asp tags and that is confusing. I will add classic asp solution.